# Memory-efficient js image management

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, optimization

### Intro

I'd like to build a webpage using html, css, javascript (jQuery), and almost 1000 images.
The html page is very long, perhaps about 5000px.

When the user scrolls through the page, I would like the images to play like a flipbook as the background of the page. For instance if there are 1000 images and the user has scrolled 32% of the page, they will be looking at the 320th image. If they have scrolled the whole way, they are looking at the 1000th image.

How ought I go about handling this *efficiently*? The file size for each image is roughly 150kb and I would most importantly like to avoid compressing these images any further.

### What I've Tried

1. Never removing images from memory

   As the user scrolls more images are loaded, and previous images are set to `display: none;`. This approach works, but becomes *very* laggy as the user scrolls further and further.
2. Only keeping 40 images in memory at a time

   As the user scrolls the current image is loaded, and 20 images ahead and behind the current image are loaded. Any images more than 20 flips away are "removed from memory". *Still* gets laggy (probably because I'm not handling memory properly - I'll get to that)

### Question 1

What technique do you guys recommend I use on this project?

I feel as if my option 2 should be effective, but I'd love to hear more suggestions.

### Question 2

**How do I properly remove images not only from the DOM, but from memory?**

I'm fairly certain if I want this project to be successful I *will* need to wind up removing images.

### Current approach

Here's my current approach:

```
var imageNum = -The current image number that ought to be showing-;
var flip = -the container element holding all the images-;

flip.children().each(function(i, e) { 
    var jE = $(e);
    var childInd = parseInt(jE.data('page-number'));

    if (childInd < imageNum - 20 || childInd > imageNum + 20) {
        jE.removeAttr('src');
        jE.remove();
        jE = null;
        e = null;
    }
});
```

*This part in particular is where I am unsure I am correctly freeing memory:*

```
jE.removeAttr('src');
jE.remove();
jE[0] = null;
e = null;
```

I put those lines together after a bit of googling. There are no event-handlers on the images, so I'm fairly sure that is not a concern.

How do I enable the image memory to be collected by the GC? Is what I'm doing *sufficient* to allow the GC to free the memory from these images?

Comment: There's no 'known or consistent' way to force garbage collection in JS. You just need to make sure you clean up all references to the objects so they can be garbage collected. To that end, the lines around `jE.remove();` are essentially useless as they only clean up local scope. `jE.remove();` is the only one you need. Have you profiled the app in chrome or safari to see if memory is your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the comment and I'm aware - I made a small edit right in the second-last paragraph to clarify!

Comment: Can you post the code around where you insert the images into the DOM?

Comment: The removal and reinsertion of images from and into the DOM probably costs you more memory than adding them once... Also, you should have a look at [LazyLoading](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/)

Comment: for those of you wondering, I've solved the problem on my own. I was using multiple <img src=""/> elements, which caused the lag. Loading the images in a new Image() object and then just changing the src attribute on a single <img/> was what fixed my problem.

Comment: @Gershy For inquisitive minds out there, this is the good ol' pooling pattern. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern

Answer (score 0):

You Can use image sprites , in which you can make a single image for multiple images and can fetch each image with the coordinates .